# Get the last insert id

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Hello I am using cakePHP 1.3 and I am unable to retreive the last inserted row's id. I actually am using $this->Model->id to retreive the last inserted id but I am unable to get the id. When tried to check what is return type, it says as bool(false), which means nothing is returned.

Here I am loading a different model in a different controller, so would that be the issue?? But even though I am loading, I get back nothing!!

```
$this->loadModel('Contact');
$this->Contact->query("insert into contacts(tblContact_firstName,tblContact_lastName,tblContact_company,tblContact_department,tblContact_address,tblContact_country,tblContact_city,tblContact_state,tblContact_zipcode,tblContact_phone1,tblContact_email1) values('$sanitizedFormData[fname]','$sanitizedFormData[lname]','','$sanitizedFormData[company]','$sanitizedFormData[address]','$sanitizedFormData[country]','$sanitizedFormData[city]','$sanitizedFormData[state]','$sanitizedFormData[zip]','$sanitizedFormData[phone]','$sanitizedFormData[email]');");

$this->loadModel('Contact');
$contactId = $this->Contact->id;
```

And when I printed the $this->Contact array recursively, I found the value of "id" key empty. So that explains why I was receiving an empty value.

Now given my situation, how would I get the last inserted id, specific to the controller Contact?

Comment: There is probably a cake specific function for this, but mySQL has `LAST_INSERT_ID()`

Comment: Well I actually am trying to avoid another database call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `query()` you loose a lot of automagic cakephp provides. Use `save()` instead.

In fact, you even do not need to load Contact in this case. You can execute any query from the current controller with `query()` even saving to any other table.

You can also avoid using `loadModel()` if your current model is somehow associated with Contact (`$this->CurrentModel->AnotherOne->Contact->save(...)`).

Comment: So if I use save, then would I be able to retrieve the last insert id?

Comment: I hope yes. At least I have never had the problem with retrieving last insert id. Take a look here too - http://api13.cakephp.org/class/model#method-ModelgetLastInsertID.

Comment: @macha yes, it's the save() method usage that will automatically set the model's ID.  In general, try to use the Cake built-ins; they do a lot of handy stuff automatically for you (like setting the model id).

Comment: Also, how would I know how a current model is connected to another one and that other model is connected to my destination model

Comment: If you have correct associations defined in the models they will be connected by calling them the way I mentioned above.

Answer (score 8):

I think you just want to do:

```
$this->getLastInsertID();
```

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/additional-methods-and-properties.html#model-getlastinsertid

Answer (score 4):

If this is MySQl you could use "SELECT from contacts LAST_INSERT_ID()" query to get last ID.
or just "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()"

For MSSQL it is "SELECT @@IDENTITY".

This bypasses any solution in cakePHP though, so there might be a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can get `last inserted record id` by

```
echo $this->ModelName->getLastInsertID();
```

Alternately, you can use:

```
echo $this->ModelName->getInsertID();
```

This methods can be found in cake/libs/model/model.php on line 2775

**Note:** This function doesn't work if you run the insert query manually